# MsiExec uninstall issue

Tags: windows, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer

When performing a silent uninstallation of an msi package, is there any way to bypass this kind of dialog?

[image]

I've tried with the `/Passive` and `/Quiet` parameter, but it does not take any effect.

If this is not possible, what silent alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `msiexec.exe /qb /x` this should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks but not, it still asks for the confirmation.

Comment: what are you trying to uninstall ?

Comment: I'm triying to uninstall a hidden and useless component of Visual Studio 2013 (a developer IDE) silentlly. But that thing does not really matter, the problem is not that specific installer, this happens with any other `MSI` installer that finds a conflict when you try to uninstall a program that maybe will corrupt other associated program (totally untrue in this case) then that kind of confirmation box appears and I would like to know if `msiexec` provides a parameter to automatically confirm that kind of advise, a simple `/Quiet` does not confirm the advise and it cancels the uninstallation.

Comment: try `msiexec.exe /x /quiet /passive /qn`

Comment: No, it does not works.

Comment: Humm, maybe if you log the uninstall process, the UI will be disabled ! just thinking about it..because non of the quite parameters worked! and that's weird, there is something missing !
let's try this one `msiexec /x /qn /norestart /force "{regKey}" /log "C:\log.txt"`